# Uncommitted transaction using Hibernate + Bitronix

Tags: hibernate, transactions, bitronix

Hi All: I am having problems with committing transactions using Hibernate + Bitronix where the call to persist occurs in another jar. For example, if I have jarA and jarB. JarA begins a transaction and calls a method in jarB. The method in jarB persists its data. Finally jarA commits the transaction. However, the commit doesn't go through as Bitronix throws an exception saying there is no transaction.

Some relevant code:

```
void doStuffInJarA() {
    BitronixTransactionManager btm = TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager();
    btm.begin();
    callMethodInJarB();
    btm.commit();
}
...
void callMethodInJarB() {
    MyDAO mydao = new MyDAO();
    mydao.persist(myObject);
}
```

Comment: could u plz post ur error log?

Comment: Hi: The error is happening here: BitronixTransaction t = tm.getCurrentTransaction(); t.commit(); Java throws NPE at t.commit(). Sorry I can't be any more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because you accidentally instantiated two (or more) transaction managers.

You began the transaction in one transaction manager, and are trying to execute it under another.  Determine which transaction manager is good, and remove the other one from the project (code/spring context/etc).

Sometimes this happens because of how some of the abstraction libraries use the classloaders, so it can be tricky to debug.